# What Bootstrap 4 components work on css only (without Jquery, Tether)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I have previously used bootstrap 3 css only with angular 2 for an application which did not require jquery dependent bootstrap components like modal, carousel etc.

I am now considering using bootstrap 4 with Angular 2 and have looked through bootstrap 4 [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/), but still confused on what components depend on jquery and/or tether.js and what components work if I include css alone. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Current Alpha (6) has 3 sets of CSS.

- `bootstrap-reboot` - defines only Html standard tags
- `bootstrap-grid` - defines the mobile-firt grid system, e.g. `.container` & `.col-x-x`
- `bootstrap` - full version

Generally speaking, the first two above will not require the JS dependencies.

If you want to dig deeper then a quick look at the [bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap.scss) source has the JS dependant items listed separately.  Thus, the non-JS dependent components are:

**Core CSS**

- reboot
- type
- images
- code
- grid
- tables
- forms
- buttons

**Components**

- transitions
- dropdown
- button-group
- input-group
- custom-forms
- nav
- navbar
- card
- breadcrumb
- pagination
- badge
- jumbotron
- alert
- progress
- media
- list-group
- responsive-embed
- close

**Other**

- print

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, as of 4.4, the [only components that require JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js) are

- Alerts for dismissing
- Buttons for toggling states and checkbox/radio functionality
- Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators
- Collapse for toggling visibility of content
- Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
- Modals for displaying, positioning, and scroll behavior
- Navbar for extending our Collapse plugin to implement responsive behavior
- Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
- Scrollspy for scroll behavior and navigation updates